# Is it possible to set the auth type when evaluating resolver code via AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

### Aim

- To evaluate an AWS AppSync resolver template with a mock context identity for [`AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorization`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference-js.html#identity).
- Using `Boto3` AppSync Client with either [`evaluate_mapping_template`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appsync/client/evaluate_mapping_template.html#) or [`evaluate_code`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appsync/client/evaluate_code.html) functions.

### Problem

If I pass in the following context:

```
    context = {
        "arguments": {},
        "stash": {},
        "source": {},
        "result": {},
        "identity": {"username": "user"},
        "request": {},
    }
```

for the most basic resolver which just returns the `ctx.identity.username`.

The response contains an error:

```bash
'error': {'message': 'Unrecognized field "username" (class com.amazonaws.deepdish.common.identity.LambdaAuthIdentity), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "resolverContext"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.amazonaws.deepdish.transform.model.MappingTemplateContext$MappingTemplateContextBuilder["identity"]->com.amazonaws.deepdish.common.identity.LambdaAuthIdentity["username"])'}
```

It seems like it is only using the `AWS_LAMBDA authorization`, which from the docs:

> The identity has the following form:
>
> ```
> type AppSyncIdentityLambda = {
>   resolverContext: any;
> };
> ```

I can't see how to specify which type of authorisation type should be used for evaluation.

I've tried changing the content of the resolver and simplifying the context as per the problem description. I can't find anything about it in the docs and there are [examples online](https://medium.com/tech-p7s1/unit-testing-for-aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-templates-16d2d4c468c7) where it says it should work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue, it seems the examples online which work as expected use VTL templates. However testing JS resolver with Cognito identity as part of the context doesn't seem to work. See also related issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/242#issuecomment-1867610909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `identity` object needs to contain all required fields (it's not documented).

I was able to fix the issue by strictly following the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/test-debug-resolvers-js.html

An example identity object would look like the following:

```
identity: {
  sub : "uuid",
  issuer : " https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}",
  username : "Nadia",
  claims : { },
  sourceIp :[  "x.x.x.x" ],
  defaultAuthStrategy : "ALLOW",
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michał! That works for me now! You're right, it's not documented at all that you need all the fields for testing